# How do I restore the behavior of the fn key after Mojave update?

Tags: macos, mojave

I updated to Mojave yesterday and my fn key seems to have changed behavior.  Previously, I could hold fn and press delete to foward delete.  Now, if I press the fn key, it has different behaviors.

In spotlight, it clears my search.  In chromes URL window, it highlights the URL.  In vim, I'm not really sure what it's doing but it exits insert mode as a result.  I miss my fn key. :(

Comment: did you check your keyboard shortcuts

Comment: what app were you using before to have those keyboard shortcuts

Comment: @Buscar웃, yeah.  I looked for keyboard shortcuts that may have replaced the original behavior.  I didn't have an app that provided the behavior.  Fn + Delete has always forward deleted for me.  Up until yesterday.  :(

Comment: Why does Apple always does that to us ?

Comment: I know right!?  I want my cheese back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo . . . I've done this to myself.  I'm not sure how I've done it, and I don't like answering my own questions, but in case anybody else finds themselves in this situation . . . here goes.

I never use caps lock so I typically remap caps lock to control.  While I was doing this, evidently, I also remapped fn to escape by accident.

1. Apple > System Preference > Keyboard
2. Click 'Modifier Keys'
3. Sometimes there's a dropdown allowing you to remap the fn key (it seems like it's only there when you have an external keyboard too which may be why I couldn't find it when I looked here before to reset the behavior)

[image: screen capture of keyboard modifier keys mappings]